# Nginx server blank page

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

When I connect to my web server, the page loads but remains blank.
On developper mode, the console shows no error and all the requests are returning a normal response. The html response of the page is the following
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UjAS.png).

Other times the page does not respond and the html code is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1x9Nb.png).

Nothing is wrong in nginx/error.log nor in access.log.
This is my nginx conf file:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen       443 ssl;

    server_name  servername.com;

    ssl_certificate      /etc/ssl/certificate.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssl/private.key;


    location / {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass https://0.0.0.0:5173;
        proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
    }
}
```

My app is built with vite:

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig} from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import mkcert from 'vite-plugin-mkcert'

const env = process.env.NODE_ENV
console.log("Environment is : " + env)
const HOST = "http://backend:8081"

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    mkcert()
  ],
  build: {
    target: 'esnext', //browsers can handle the latest ES features
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ['vue', 'vue-router', "@auth0/auth0-spa-js"],
      output: {
        globals: {
          vue: 'Vue'
        }
      }
    }
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  },
  server: {
    https: true,
    Port : 5173,
    host : "0.0.0.0",
    proxy: {
      "^/api/.": {
        target: HOST,
        secure: true,
        rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/api/, ''),
      }
    },
  }
})
```

And finally these are my index.html and main.js:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta name=”robots” content=”noindex”>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">
    <title>Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'

import App from './App.vue'
import Login from './Login.vue'
import Home from './Home.vue'
import store from './store'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'
import PrimeVue from 'primevue/config';
import "primevue/resources/themes/lara-light-indigo/theme.css";     
import "primevue/resources/primevue.min.css";
import InputText from 'primevue/inputtext';
import Calendar from 'primevue/calendar';
import Dialog from 'primevue/dialog';
import Textarea from 'primevue/textarea';
import Dropdown from 'primevue/dropdown';
import Checkbox from 'primevue/checkbox';
import Notifications from '@kyvg/vue3-notification'
import * as VueRouter from "vue-router";

import cors from 'cors'

import IssuesDialog from './assets/IssuesDialog.vue'
import AccessDWC from './assets/AccessDWC.vue'

const corsConfig = {
    credentials:true,
    origin:"*",
}

const routes = [
    { path: '/', component: Home, meta : { requiredAuth : true, }},
    { path: '/login', component: Login },
  ]
const router = VueRouter.createRouter({
    history: VueRouter.createWebHistory(  ),
    routes,
})

router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {   
    let isAuthenticated = store.state.auth.isAuthenticated;
    if(to.path !== '/login' && to.meta.requiredAuth && !isAuthenticated){
        next('/login');
    } else if (from.path === '/login' && to.meta.requiredAuth && isAuthenticated){
        next();
    } else {
        next();
    }
})

const app = createApp(App);
app.use(router)

app.use(PrimeVue)
    .use(store, cors(corsConfig))
    .use(Notifications)
app.component('IssuesDialog', IssuesDialog)
    .component('AccessDWC', AccessDWC)
    .component('Dialog', Dialog)
    .component('Textarea', Textarea)
    .component('Calendar', Calendar)
    .component('InputText', InputText)
    .component('Dropdown', Dropdown)
    .component('Checkbox', Checkbox)
    .component('Login', Login)
app.mount('#app');
```

Since my app works perfectly fine on my local machine, maybe that's to much information but I have no idea where the problem might come from. I tried almost every nginx config possible, including the one given by @Philippe in the answer below.

Comment: `0.0.0.0` ip address is [very specific](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0). It may be considered as localhost, but not for sure. On your local machine, is it okay with both http and https ?

Comment: On my machine only https works with http I get "The connection was reset". Do you think it can be due to aut0 config @Philippe ?

Answer (score 0):

First, I suggest you to isolate port 80, in order to redirect requests to the https server block :

```
server {
      listen       80;

      server_name  servername.com;

      return 301 https://servername.com$request_uri;
}
```

Then, in the https server block, you need to define the `root` directive, to say where the web folder is. You must also precise the real ip of your server in the `proxy_pass` directive.

```
server {
    listen       443 ssl;

    server_name  servername.com;

    ssl_certificate      /etc/ssl/certificate.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssl/private.key;

    root /path/to/web/folder; # can be in the location block. 

    location / {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://real.ip.to.server:5173/;
        proxy_max_temp_file_size 0; # you can also try to disable this line
    }
}
```